# Como reemplazar palabras con tilde en JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, condiciones, text, str-replace

Estoy intentando reemplazar dos palabras con tilde, pero algo falla:

Quiero que cambien en un intervalo de dos segundos "La educaci**ó**n" a "La empat**í**a", y de nuevo a la primera y en bucle.

El resultado se queda en el primer console.log del primer If, y no pasa de ahí. Gracias de antemano

```
var timer = setTimeout(changeText(), 2000);

function changeText(){
    var oldText = $("#pageHeaderDescription").text();

    if ($('#pageHeaderDescription:contains("educaci\u00F3n")').length > 0) {
        oldText.replace("educaci\u00F3n", "empat\u00EDa");
        console.log(oldText);
    } else if ($('#pageHeaderDescription:contains("empat\u00EDa")').length > 0) {
        oldText.replace("empat\u00EDa", "educaci\u00F3n");
        console.log(oldText);
    }

    $("#pageHeaderDescription").text(oldText);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace lo siguiente `oldtext=oldText.replace("educaci\u00F3n", "empat\u00EDa");` tu variable no se esta actualizando con el nuevo valor.